# How can i interact with a remote GUI using psexec?

Tags: psexec

I want to test a remote applications using PSExec, the problem is i can't interact with it. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

PSexec works by remotely creating a service configured to run a command of your choice. In more recent versions of windows OS (Vista, 2008, 7) a service is not allowed to have an interactive component. Yes, there are deprecated options to allow interactivity, but windows will give it a new windows session that is separate from others. The user will see a prompt to reveal any GUI componant that is kind of similar to User Account Control. When you accept the prompt, a wholly blank desktop is loaded with the GUI part of your service.